# Building terminal-ide from source (package com.android.sdklib.build does not exist)?

Tags: android, ant, build, terminal-ide

Working on Ubuntu 14.04, I'm trying to compile:

https://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/ (via https://github.com/math4youbyusgroupillinois/terminal-ide)

... because its `rsync` fails in Android 5+ with "*error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.*"

This is not a gradle project, so I'm guessing it uses `ant`; so I do:

```
$ JAVA_HOME=/path/to/android/jdk1.6.0_45 ant debug
Buildfile: /path/to/src/terminal-ide-git/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.3.3
 [checkenv] Installed at /path/to/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: TermIDE
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.1.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for TermIDE...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /path/to/src/terminal-ide-git/bin/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /path/to/src/terminal-ide-git/bin/rsLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for TermIDE...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] No changes in the AndroidManifest files.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] No changed resources. R.java and Manifest.java untouched.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 1509 source files to /path/to/src/terminal-ide-git/bin/classes
    [javac] /path/to/src/terminal-ide-git/src/com/spartacusrex/spartacuside/external/apkbuilder.java:9: package com.android.sdklib.build does not exist
    [javac] import com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilderMain;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] /path/to/src/terminal-ide-git/src/com/spartacusrex/spartacuside/external/apkbuilder.java:15: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: class ApkBuilderMain
    [javac] public class apkbuilder extends ApkBuilderMain{}
    [javac]                                 ^
```

... but I get `package com.android.sdklib.build does not exist`.

So what can I do, to build Terminal IDE from source?

Answer (score 0):

Someone on XDA has recompiled the binaries in terminal IDE statically and repackaged it. This doesn't technically answer your question, but it should still solve your problem. You can find it [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=57292384&postcount=68).